# javascript await and python await, are they same concept?

Tags: javascript, python, async-await

From a user point of view,

When we think of `for` loop..
We could say `for` loop in javascript or python are the same thing conceptually.

Can we say `await` in both languages are conceptually same?

I smell, this can be a bad question.. but albeit interesting question for me..

Comment: For the most part, yeah. async/await just means to use an event loop, in other words (usually) running stuff concurrently on the same thread. The use of await to say "pause execution of this function until this returns" is the same. JS wraps that logic in to use Promises but it ends up being the same thing. Return value on success, raise error on failure.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR **No**. They are **NOT** same.

The biggest difference is,

An `async` Javascript function **will run** if invoked, **even if not awaited**.
`await` here is used to make sure the subsequent execution is done sequentially. ie., write code including an async function, just like for a synchronous code. Prior to async-await, JS code can get pretty complex since asynchronous functions will have be handled using Promises and Promise chaining can impact code readability pretty quickly.

So in a way, `async-await` in JS may be termed as syntactic sugar for Promise handling.

Incase of Python, when an `awaitable` object is invoked, a coroutine object is created. But this coroutine is **not run** unless it is **awaited**.
Here the use of `await` is to run the coroutine.